# Forwarding Out Of Office replies in SFMC with Enterprise Reply Mail Management

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have to forward all the out of office replies to one mailbox.

As Gmail and Outlook consider Marketing Cloud as a mailing list, the out of office replies will not be forwarded. But Salesforce told me this is possible, with **Enterprise Reply Mail Management**.

So Enterprise RMM is now enabled in the parent BU and two child BUs.
So I've created rules & collections (strange: in the senderprofiles of my child BUs, I can only use the collections of my parent BU).

Unfortunately I still do not receive the out of office replies in the certain mailbox.

Does someone has experience with this issue (forwarding out of office replies)?

Thank you very, very much!

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your RMM configuration?

Comment: It might have to do with DMARC, check this resource:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_dmarc_fwd_reply_rewrite.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi both, in the mean team the ERMM is working (thanks to the DMARC)! But only for manual replies with out of office terms. So 'automatic' out of office replies are not being forwarded. Any of you might know why these are not forwarded? Thank you very much! @JonasLamberty

Comment: Hi, yes. One of the main ideas of setting up RMM is that it filters automatic replies. The idea being that you do not want to flood your support inbox with 10000 out-of-office replies if you send around Christmas time. 
So the RMM settings by default are set to  only "route  _remaining_ replies" (after filtering) to your inbox as it says in the configuration UI.

The option to "Delete Auto-Replies and Out-of-Office" is set to "yes" by default. Setting it to "no" should "fix" the behavior - if really desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

confirmed from the comments:

It might have to do with DMARC, check this resource: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_dmarc_fwd_reply_rewrite.htm&type=5