# Auto replies are not being forwarded to the inbox configured in RMM

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

I have configured the RMM like this:
The normal replies are coming to the configured inbox in the custom RMM but the auto replies/Out of box replies are forwared to the inbox in the sender profile we want all the messages to be forwarded to the inbox in the RMM setting
[image]

Answer (score 0):

RMM is not my strength in SFMC but I think you should look in DMARC
Give this a read: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_dmarc_fwd_reply_rewrite.htm&type=5

Also thank you Jonas Lamberty for a post you did here that helped me reply to this post:
[Forwarding Out Of Office replies in SFMC with Enterprise Reply Mail Management](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306579/forwarding-out-of-office-replies-in-sfmc-with-enterprise-reply-mail-management)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).